# converting Logging data to JSON

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to convert logging data to JSON to show it in ChatBot.I tried logging.Formatter but data still isn't showing in chatbot it throws an error.
I tried `userInput = logging.Formatter(user_input)`.
After this I tried `userInput = logging.Formatter(user_input)`
`user = userInput.json()` but it didn't work as well.
How can I convert logging data to json for chatbot. Where I'm committing mistake kindly correct it. Code is below

this is the error I'm getting.

An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: this is the error.........     An error has occurred: Invalid Lambda Response: Received error response from Lambda: Unhandled

Comment: You should add the error you are getting to your question. Maybe also simplify your code sample to just the area you are trying to add so it's easier to reproduce.

Comment: ok I did now see if you can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see the logging info in the chatbot, you can convert that object into string and return it to chatbot.

```
def response(message):
    return {
        "dialogAction":{
            "type":"Close",
            "fulfillmentState":"Fulfilled",
            "message":{
                "contentType":"PlainText",
                "content":message
            }
        }
    }

return response(str(logging_info_object))
```

Hope it helps.